# Report password protection

Tags: java, php, passwords, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have reports and i can download this reports using Jasper Reports and JavaBridge. I need now to protect this reports (PDF).

I found this in Java

```
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OWNER_PASSWORD, "hi");
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.USER_PASSWORD, "hi");
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_ENCRYPTED, Boolean.TRUE);
```

I change this for this:

```
    $exporter-setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterParameter")-OWNER_PASSWORD, "hi");
    $exporter-setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterParameter")-USER_PASSWORD, "hi");
    $exporter-setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporterParameter")-IS_ENCRYPTED, Boolean.TRUE);
```

But doenst work. Can anyone help me ?? Thanks for all!!

Comment: try to use only the String value of the parameter as example for OWNER_PASSWORD it is "Owner Password"

Comment: Doesn´t work. Thanks for the reply.
I try to do something. But i only take the pdf with errors....